# Dynamic array with string key

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have array:

```
Array
(
[CS] => Array
    (
        [Zomblerz] => 1.80
        [Quintic] => 2.06
        [Mostly Harmless] => 2.21
        [Nexus eSports] => 1.70
        [WinOut.net] => 2.73
        [Ace Gaming] => 1.48
        [Luminosity Gaming] => 3.68
        [Natus Vincere] => 1.30
    )

[LoL] => Array
    (
        [Jin Air Green Wings] => 1.17
        [Incredible Miracle] => 5.40
        [Rebels Anarchy] => 1.27
        [SBENU Sonicboom] => 3.92
        [SK Telecom T1] => 1.19
        [CJ Entus] => 4.95
        [KOO Tigers] => 1.38
        [NaJin e-mFire] => 3.15
    )

[StarCraft] => Array
    (
        [Maru] => 1.48
        [Zest] => 2.73
        [Stats] => 1.90
        [ByuL] => 1.94
    )
)
```

I want display my array in Smarty with {section}, but i have a string index keys and cant do this.
I tried {foreach}, but result too bad.

```
{section name=i loop=$odds}
<table>
  <th> here i want game name... </th>
  {section name=j loop=$odds[i]}
  <tr>
     <td> here team name - here team number </td>
     ...
  </tr>
  {/section}
 </table>
 {/section}
```

Can u help me?

P.S. sorry for my english(

Comment: array_values( ); will remove the string keys

Comment: why do you want to use `{section}` when the doc specifically say [`A {section} is for looping over sequentially indexed arrays of data, unlike {foreach} which is used to loop over a single associative array.`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl) - http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix  `array_values()` would cause an issue for the OP, where they want to do `<th> here i want game name... </th>`, which looks to be the string keys.

Comment: @Sean that may be but this is what i read `i have a string index keys and cant do this` I don't use smarty, i use php :)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to get what you want in smarty.  But if all you need is the array with numeric keys, you can use `array_values()`; on the array and it will re-index the keys,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

[`{section}`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl) is for looping over **numerically-indexed arrays only**.

[`{foreach}`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) is used to loop over an **associative array**

Your desired result is demonstrated in [`Example 7.8. {foreach} with nested item and key`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#id2802172) - http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#id2802172

Your code would look something like -

```
{foreach key=game item=odd from=$odds}
  <table>
  <th>{$game}</th>
  {foreach key=team item=teamnumber from=$odd}
    <tr>
      <td>{$team}: {$teamnumber}</td>
    </tr>
  {/foreach}
  </table>
{/foreach}
```

---

**edit**

per your comment, if you want to change your table layout, using

```
{if $smarty.foreach.teams.index % 2 == 0}...{/if}
```

you could do something like -

```
{foreach key=game item=odd from=$odds}
  <table>
  <th>{$game}</th>
    <tr>
  {foreach name=teams key=team item=teamnumber from=$odd}
    {if $smarty.foreach.teams.index % 2 == 0}
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {/if}
      <td>{$team}</td>
      <td>{$teamnumber}</td>
  {/foreach}
    </tr>
  </table>
{/foreach}
```

see http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.index

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if i want place two teams and two numbers in row like this: <table><th>game1</th><tr><td>team1</td><td>odd1</td><td>team2</td><td>odd2</td></tr><tr><td>team3</td><td>odd3</td><td>team4</td><td>odd4</td></tr></table>, can foreach do this?

Comment: if that is your desired result, why did you not put that in your original question?

Comment: i am newbie in Smarty, just learning all cases) thx for help again, start read manual)

Comment: in your example only even index, but i want two teams in one step of foreach loop... can Smarty do it? documentation have no example for this case(

Comment: I doubt it, as `foreach` means `for`-`each`. Notice how I used modulus - `% 2 == 0`. This allows you do something after every 2, which could be creating a new row, or other html. Update your question with your desired outcome, as it is difficult to know what you are wanting.